# Will GPIO still be available when connecting a BoosterPack on any Launchpad?

Tags: gpio, launchpad

I had this question in mind while exploring the BoosterPacks for the TI Tiva C series launchpads. Let's say you connected KenTec display to the board, you still have access to the female headers on the bottom of the board. The question is when the display is operating and functioning, will you still be able to use any GPIO for other external circuitry or systems or anything ?

The question applies on any other boosterpack.

Comment: I guess it depends on the boosterpack. The boosterpack peripherals will use some of the pins, but the unused ones should remain available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any except the ones used by the booster pack. Booster packs are intended to pass through any unused pins. Most packs have schematics available to tell you which pins are used.